# Display image with JavaScript FileReader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm trying to display an image before uploading it via `javascript / jQuery`.

I'm executing this code in the ADD-Method of the jQuery Fileuploader. The data-attribute provides me with the file

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var img = $('<img></img>');
  img.attr('src', e.target.result);
  $("#general_dropable").append(img);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file); // Retrieved from the data-attribute of the ADD-Method of the jQuery Fileuploader
```

Displaying works fine. When I drag the image in `Google-Chrome`, however, I'm getting this error from Chrome:

```
He's dead, Jim! Either Chrome ran out of memory or the process for the webpage was terminated for some other reason. To continue, reload or go to another page.
```

Dragging the image in `Firefox` works fine.

The image source is the **actual source code of the image**, not an absolute path.

Is there a workaround to this `bug`?

Thank you very much.

**Edit**

You can see a live example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/LvsYc/1669/
Just drag the image after uploading and the error will appear (In Chrome)

Comment: replicate issue on jsfiddle. BTW, provide more context in your posted code.

Answer (score -1):

I just found this question on stackoverflow. But looking at the jsfiddle I don't get this exception in Chrome any more (Chrome 46). To me it looked like you forgot to define the "file" variable in your function when you write it to the DOM (reader.readAsDataURL). But in **your** jsfiddle it seems fixed:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();            
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

.. this is not my answer as it was fixed already in jsfiddle ... but as I was searching for a solution for my problem i wanted to clarify things here as this might help others.